# Is a closed ball of $L^p$ closed in $L^1$ for finite measures?

Tags: real-analysis

So I am trying to figure out whether a closed ball of $L^p$ is closed in $L^1$ in finite measures.

Assuming the ball is of radius $1$, we know that it is contained in some ball when considering the $L^1$ norm. That follows from the proof of $L^p\subset L^1$. However, I do not know how to proceed from here. We take $f_n\to f$ in $L^1$ where $\|f_n\|_p\leq1$ and want to show that $\|f\|_p\leq1$. I do not know how to do that. It would be easy if we could somehow show that $f_n$ converges in $L^p$ but I do not think that is necessarily true. The question has been asked here: [Prove Lp ball closed in L1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2788208/prove-lp-ball-closed-in-l1) But I do not really understand the solutions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of Fatou's Lemma: Let $\|f_n\|_p \leq M$ for all $n$ and $f_n \to  f$ in $L^{1}$. Then there is  a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging a.e. to $f$. Since $\int |f_{n_k}|^{p} \leq M^{p}$ for each $k$ Fatou's Lemma gives $\int |f|^p \leq M^{p}$ which proves that $f$ belongs to the closed ball of radius $M$ in $L^{p}$.

Comment: Wow that is simple! Thank youQ